# How to keep visual studio 2010 from saving unit test results?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I do TDD so I run a LOT of unit tests per day. Every time I run a test, visual studio saves a new 12mb folder on my disk.

I went to the option panel > test tools > test execution and limited the number of old test results to 1. It didn't do a thing.

How can I disable that feature?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper unit test runner by any chance?

Comment: i wasn't using resharper (:/) and no, i never resolved it.

Comment: as far as I am aware you cannot turn this off just limit to 1 as you have done.

Comment: but it didn't even work ! i had to empty my disk every week.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the following cleanup script in your solution current test settings:

```
FOR /D %%I IN ("%TestDir%\..\*") DO (IF NOT "%%~fsI"=="%TestDir%" rmdir "%%~fsI" /s /q)
```